Opencsv - Map different columns to same type
I have a CSV like:
Mom;Dad;Childs
Estelle;Brad;Joe John Julia

I want to map Mom and Dad each to a bean Person and Childs to a list of Person.
But opencsv complains about the fact it has encountered same class multiple times.
Is there a way to deal with this problem?
class MyCsv {
   @CsvRecurse
   private Person mom;
   @CsvRecurse
   private Person dad;
   // I don't know yet how to manage childs
}

class Person {
   @CsvBindByName(column = "Mom|Dad")
   private String name;
}

